# Options on XSD attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Is it possible to define options for XSD attributes? I wanted that the element "where" to have the attribute "logic" and can have only the value "OR" or "AND".

Example:

```
<where logic="OR"> <!-- valid -->
    ...
</where>

<where logic="XPTO"> <!-- invalid -->
    ...
</where>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

First of all you have to define a simple type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="boolString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="AND"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="OR"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then you have to define a `where` element that contains a `logic` attibute of type `boolString`:

```
<xs:element name="where">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="logic" type="boolString" />
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```